# How can I display a user's tasks which is related by the same tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a todo application via Ruby on Rails. I have created my own model for tags and taggings without the use of act_as_taggable gem. I have used devise for user authentication. One of my feature is to have a page which can show all of the user's tasks which is related by tags. However I have tried to change my show and index method in the tags controller to incorporate current_user but it always throws me this error

(undefined method `tag` for # Did you mean? tags tap):
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eunV4.png)

I am unable to figure out how I can edit my code to create tags within the current_user and properly process the tag_list for my current_user.

This is are the relevant codes:

Task model

```
has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
validates :item, presence: true,
                 length: { minimum: 5 } 
belongs_to :user
validate :due_date_cannot_be_in_the_past

def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by!(name: name).tasks
end

def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(" ")
end

def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(" ").map do |name|
        Tag.where(name: name).first_or_create!
    end
end

def due_date
    due.to_s
end

def due_date=(str)
    self.due = Chronic.parse(str).to_date.to_s

rescue
    @invalid_date = true
end

def validate
    errors.add :due, 'is not a valid date' if @invalid_date
end

def due_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if due.past?
        errors.add(:due_date, "is not a valid date")
    end
end
end
```

Task Controller:

```
def index
    @incomplete_tasks = Task.where(complete: false)
    @complete_tasks = Task.where(complete: true)
end

def show
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @task = current_user.tasks.build
end

def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

    if @task.save
    redirect_to @task
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    if @task.update(task_params)
        redirect_to @task
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    redirect_to tasks_path
end

def complete
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attribute(:complete, true)
    flash[:notice] = "Task Marked as Complete"
    redirect_to tasks_path
end

private 
    def task_params
        params.require(:task).permit(:item, :description, :tag_list, :due)  
    end
end
```

Tags Controller:

```
def show
    @tag = current_user.tag.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @tag = current_user.tag.all 
end
```

Please do let me know if any other information is needed to make this problem clearer.

Comment: Hi. Please read this https://thoughtbot.com/blog/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through article to understand how nested attributes work with has many through.

Comment: So is tag_list a nested attribute of tasks?

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Comment: Is it possible if you could explain abit further on why tag_list is a nested attribute of tasks and why it isnt tags which is the nested attribute of tasks?

Comment: I get this error now: "Validation failed: User must exist, User can't be blank"